# Can I limit my SSH Tunneling Speed?

Tags: ssh, tunneling

So, I'm kind of making sshusers  for ssh tunneling to surf some content which is blocked by my country. But, I don't want somebody to slow down others internet speed , therefore I want to limit the connection to, eg: 100KB/s. I know trickled can be used in this situation but how?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
trickle -d 100 -u 100 firefox
```

Comment: Or simply: `trickle -d 100 -u 100 ssh -D 1080 remotehost`

Comment: Actually I have to limit the bandwidth on Server side so I used trickled

Answer (score 0):

Check out wondershaper:

http://lartc.org/wondershaper/

Comment: ok I am trying.

Comment: have you used this? because, I little bit complex, I did not understand how to limit global network of the server.

Comment: Yea, I'm using it.  It actually tries to optimize for port 22 traffic but you want to limit port 22 traffic.

Comment: Its not working because of kernel restrictions. I have a vps.