# Can I limit my SSH Tunneling Speed?

Tags: ssh, tunneling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I limit my SSH Tunneling Speed?](https://serverfault.com/questions/270781/can-i-limit-my-ssh-tunneling-speed)

So, I'm kind of making sshusers for ssh tunneling to surf some content which is blocked by my country. But, I don't want somebody to slow down others internet speed , therefore I want to limit the connection to, eg: 100KB/s. I know trickled can be used in this situation but how?

Comment: It is not quit clear how you accomplish, what you describe? Wouldn't it be easier to setup a proxy?

Comment: I am talking about socks proxy ssh -D 4444 user@server then setting socks proxy localhost 4444. I am talking about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think, is probably to use some iptables-fu to limit each connection over whatever ssh port you are using. However, would using Squid maybe be a better tool for this job?

Comment: Actually right now, I am using squid however, I think ssh forwarding performance better than squid. Therefore, I am trying make modifications. I am gonna try iptables-fu

Comment: Really?  I would _suspect_ that ssh tunneling would be slower, just because of the encryption overhead.